# javascript conflict multiple body onload events needs to be first in row

Tags: javascript, onload

I have multiple javasripts that needs using body onload event

It should be simple solution for that - just add all events in row like this:

```
<body onload="showContent();
    randomImages();
    placeIt();
    showIt();
    preloadImgs();
    initialize()">
```

But of course life isnt so simple..
fore some reason **some scripts needs to be FIRST in row.** So if I put `showContent();` first, randomimages wont execute and vice versa.

I also tried replace onload event with script like this

```
if ( typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined" )
    window.addEventListener( "load", showContent, false );
else if ( typeof window.attachEvent != "undefined" ) {
    window.attachEvent( "onload", showContent );
}
else {
    if ( window.onload != null ) {
        var oldOnload = window.onload;
        window.onload = function ( e ) {
            oldOnload( e );
            showContent();
        };
    }
    else
         window.onload = showContent;
}
```

So far I have no solution for this conflict. Does somebody have good idea?

Comment: If the functions don't throw an error, they will be executed sequentially. So I assume `showContent` is somehow failing, prevent the execution of the following.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create another function that holds all those functions and then call that one function on load? This is assuming your functions doesn't have some dependencies from the other functions.

```
showContent();randomImages();placeIt();showIt();preloadImgs();initialize()
```

can be in a bit more organized location:

```
function Init()
{
      showContent(); // if this errors out, execution for the rest stops
      randomImages();
      placeIt();
      showIt();
      preloadImgs();
      initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Felix Kling you are partly right, they are initiated sequentially but the execution time of each function will be different, therefore it is possible to create a race condition where the last function in the sequence could complete *before* the first one in the sequence completes.

The answer to this question is to build in callback into your functions. Then you can sequence them and the subsequent function will be called only when the prior one completes.
There's a pretty good answer on that subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/javascript-create-custom-callback).

However I have another point. Try to avoid using the Body Onload combination, and instead use Jquery's document .ready() function. This is because the Body Onload can fire before everything has been loaded - I think this is explained better on the JQuery website [here](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Comment: Actually $(document).ready is triggered earlier than body.onload. The onload-event will be triggered when images have loaded. The jquery document-ready is triggered when DOM is loaded, and can be safely manipulated. This means that scripts can run at the same time the images are loaded making the site load that much faster.