# Pass function name and then use in event handler

Tags: jquery, function, event-handling

What I want to do is pass the name of a function (X) as an argument into function Y, and then have function Y create an event handler that fires function X.

I want function Y to create the following:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault();X();});
```

I've tried:

```
var name="X()";
X(name);

function Y(id){
    $('#element').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault();id;});
}
```

This, predictably, doesn't work. (I'd didn't really believe it would!) But how can it be done, either (1) by doing it the way I am, or (2) passing the entire X function wholus-bolus into Y?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Create custom callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/javascript-create-custom-callback)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[here's a demo if you feel <s>doubtful</s> skeptical (sounds better) :D](http://jsfiddle.net/FeJ8x/)

```
//create x
function x(){
    alert('im from x');
}

//create y that receives the function
function y(callback){

    //bind your handler which calls callback (which was x)
    $('element').submit(function(){
        callback();
    });
}

//call y that sends over a reference of x
y(x);
```

Comment: I was neither doubtful nor skeptical :)  I just couldn't get it to work straight away because I was passing the function name as a variable (i.e., var a="my_function"; y(a);) rather than passing the function itself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

your X object must be a function, not a string.

```
function X() { /*code*/ }
```

You can prevent the default action by returning false at the end of X;

```
function X() { 
  /*code*/ 
  return false;
}
```

And you can use it inside another function like this:

```
function Y(callback){
  $('#element').submit(callback);
}
Y(X);
```

Comment: The clarification that I must pass the function itself and not the function name in a string was very useful. Thanks.