# Use callback from onload?

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger a new function once this function returns a callback. That is displayed here:[Create a custom callback in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript) How do I do that?

```
function loadImg (imgSrc, callback) {
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.onload = function() {
        var height = newImg.height;
        var width = newImg.width;
        if(height > width){
            console.log(false);
            if(callback) callback(false);
        } else {
            console.log(true);
            if(callback) callback(true);
        }
     }
     newImg.onerror = function () {
         if(callback) callback('error');
     }
     newImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```

Comment: please refer...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with *"once this function returns a callback"*. You can call the other function inside the callback or after you called the callback, depending how the code is related.

Comment: That function won't *return* a callback, it has no `return` statement.

Comment: @FelixKling Hrm, okay, then I need to know how to pass $('this') as a parameter to the function.

Comment: `callback(true, $('this'));` (for some value of "the function", since you have at least 6 that I can count in the question)

Comment: Use this library to detect image onload events: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded - It will also work if images are cached.

Comment: @Quentin I'm new to asyncronous stuff. How do I return the callback once the newImg has loaded?

Comment: You are already calling the callback when you call the callback in the `if` statement that checks for a `callback` that has been passed to the `loadImg` `callback` parameter.

Comment: You don't *return* callbacks. You *call* callbacks.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren — Why would you want to return anything? Nothing is going to pay attention to the return value of a load event handler.

Comment: Like you're already doing: `if(callback) callback(false);`!!! (Yes, I think a triple exclamation mark is justified).

Comment: I think it's better if you explain the problem you are actually trying to solve. What are you trying to achieve with all of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been stated, you are already calling your callback when you check for it...and then call it:

```
if(callback) callback(false);
```

Run this code (jsFiddle linked at bottom). It's the same concept as your code.

```
function doMe(something, callback) {
    console.log("Congrats, I did " + something);  
    if(callback) {
       callback();   
    }
}

doMe("the disco", function() {
   console.log("I'm a callback"); 
});
//I'm a callback
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/y3FWS/)

Alternatively, you can make it a little more "literal" and use the `call()` method to pass your arguments:

```
function doMe(something, callback) {
    console.log("Congrats, I did " + something);  
    if(callback) {
       callback.call(this, true);   
    }
}

doMe("the disco", function(bool) {
   console.log("I'm a callback. " + bool + " story"); 
});
// I'm a callback. true story
```

[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/y3FWS/1/)