# Javascript callback implementation

Tags: javascript, oop, object, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

> This has been addressed, please see the answer located at ->
>   [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript)

Comment: without seeing what's returned in your `"data"`... hard to tell

Comment: The returned data could be anything. Let us assume it is the responseText of google which contains the google.com source.

Comment: I don't understand what `eval()` has to do with invoking a callback. If you pass a function as a callback, then the function can just be called. The question really isn't clear.

Comment: replace `if (typeof (b) !== 'undefined')  with `if (typeof (b) === 'function ') ` and do `b();`

Comment: @yivi - Why are you responding to a 7 year old question that I already edited 6 years ago to include the same link listed in your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `b()` to invoke the function "b" if it is a function. You can also use the [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method to invoke a function. On the subject of callbacks, you may be interested in this article about [the Promise API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), since it provides an example of "get" and "getJSON" method that are consistent with this API.