# Executing or reloading a script after another sript was loaded

Tags: javascript

I've written a code where you have a choice between images and when you click on one of them it appears in another placeholder:

**home.php**

```
<div id="templates" class="row">
            <?php
            while ($one = $templates->fetch()) {
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
                    <a  class="thumbnail" data-price="<?= $one['price'] ?>" data-id="<?= $one['id'] ?>">
                        <img id="imgTemp" onclick="changeImage('../files/templates/blank/<?echo($one['id'])?>.jpg');changeSize();" src="/files/templates/example/<?= $one['id'] ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $one['titlep'] ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="imgDisp" src="../files/test/red-panda.jpg" alt="Red panda" class="mask" datamask="../files/test/1.png">
        </div>
```

Those images are loaded using these two functions:

```
function changeImage(imgName)
{
    image = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
    image.src = imgName;
}

function changeSize()
{
    document.getElementById('imgDisp').setAttribute("datamask","../files/test/2.png");
}
```

*changeImage* is used to take the chosen image and place it in the new div while *changeSize* is used to set an attribute "datamask". Datamask in its turn is used by another script which is in **canvasmask.js** and sets a mask on the image (e.g. square, triangle, etc.). Now, when I choose an image, no mask is applied guessing that the function in **canvasmask.js** is executed before the others. Can it be done so it is executed after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute changeSize() as callback of changeImage. If you don't know how to do it, there's a very good tuto about it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190872/2602940

Comment: Still a little hard to understand given the context. Can you show me how it works on my example?