# How to pass value into function that is a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Hello I've come across this piece of code and I have no idea how it works.

```
function firstFunction(something, else){
     //stuff being done
     return something;
}

var myFunction = firstFunction(function(a,b){
    return a*b;
},'car');
```

So I am fairly new to Javascript so I'll just say it is, a really confusing language. I understand I am declaring a variable that is assigning the firstFunction to itself and passing some noname function as first parameter and a String as a second one.

How do I go about passing the arguments into that noname functions?

Comment: What do you want to pass where? Do you want to pass `'car'` to the anonymous function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to pass values into the function(a,b). I know I can do that using myFunction.apply(this, arguments) however I don't fully understand as what is 'this' applied to and where it is used.

Comment: First of all the right term is **anonymous function**. Secondly, the the anon function being passed is probably called in the 'stuff being done' section of `firstFunction`. So you need to give us more really.

Comment: `this` refers to the global object (`window`), since you are calling the function "normally", like `foo()`. How `this` works is extensively explained in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: @FelixKling No 'car' is already passed as the second parameter to the firstFunction, I want to pass the paramaters into the anonymous function like someone has already answered. The link you provided is not working, as for 'this' I have read about it, but when I call myFunction.apply(this, arguments) I can't be refering to the window object in that situation can i?

Comment: *"I want to pass the paramaters into the anonymous function"* Which parameters? Did you really only want to know how to call the function that is in `myFunction`?

Comment: @FelixKling "Did you really only want to know how to call the function that is in myFunction" yes, yes I did as I mentioned I am fairly new to JS. Should I edit this question or should I make a new thread on function.apply and this question?

Comment: I don't see how `apply` has anything to do with that. Your question would be clearer if you had written something like "I know `myFunction` contains a function, how do I call it?". And FWIW, all functions can be called in the same ways, not matter how they were defined/where they are coming from.

Comment: I did that but in other words, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. As for apply, I am curious as to what 'object' is 'this' binded in this function calling myFunction.apply(this, arguments); I understand the usage of apply and when the regular object is passed in place of this.

Comment: When you call `myFunction.apply(this, arguments)`, the `this` *inside* the function is bound to `this` *outside* function. And if you call it in global scope, then `this` refers to `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your assessment is pretty much correct, although the code has a syntax error because you can use `else` as an identifier. These are referred to as [*anonymous* functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

Function in JavaScript can be used as parameter values or return values just as easily as any other value. This is what makes them [*first-class citizens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) of the language.

The anonymous function you pass in to `firstFunction` is returned and assigned to `myFunction` so if you want to call it, you can simply do this:

```
var result = myFunction(4, 5); // 20
```