# How do I play with async functions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

My function:

```
function dnsCheck(domain,tld) {
var dns = require('dns')
    dns.lookup(domain+'.'+tld, function (err, addresses) {
    if (err) return false // means domain avl
        else return true // means domain not avl
    })
}
```

My conditional statement:

```
if(domain_validator(domain,tld) && !dnsCheck(domain,tld)) {
res.end("avl")
}
else {
res.end("not avl")
}
```

domain_validator function is just a regex checker and returns true if it passes else false.

I am using express framework. How do I refactor my code using callbacks, promises (Q library) or generators (koa framework) to play nicely with async "dns.lookup" function? **Could anyone please modify my code using all the three approaches**?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript.

Comment: You can't return the answer from your `dnsCheck()` function because `dns.lookup()` is asynchronous and it returns sometime AFTER `dnsCheck()` has already finished and returned.  Your current return value is just being returned deep into the bowels of the network handling code and going nowhere.  You probably want to pass a callback into `dnsCheck()` and call that callback when you get the `dns.lookup()` results.  That is async programming and how you have to do it with async operations.

Comment: Yep. What you are asking is a sizeable task. I'll provide the answer for callbacks (and maybe promises) below.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks (same as the other question).

```
var dnsCheck = function(domain, tld, callback) {
  require('dns').lookup(domain + '.' + tld, function (err, addresses) {
    return callback(err == null);
  });
};

// Let's assume domainValidate is async too
var domainValidate = function(domain, tld, callback) {
  return callback(true);  // Add your logic here
};

dnsCheck(domain, tld, function(isChecked) {
  domainValidate(domain, tld, function(isValid) {

    if (isChecked && isValid) {
      res.end('available');
    } else {
      res.end('unavailable');
    }
  });
});
```

Promises (I don't know Q, but you get the idea, I hope).

```
var dnsCheck = function(domain, tld) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    require('dns').lookup(domain + '.' + tld, function (err, addresses) {
      if (err) return reject();
      resolve();
    });
  });      
};    

// Domain validate will be similar  

dnsCheck(domain, tld).then(function() {
  return domainValidate(domain, tld);
})
.then(function() {
  res.end('available');
})
.catch(function() {
  res.end('unavailable');
});
```

I'll leave someone else to show how it's done with generators. I'm not as familiar with them as I am promises.