# Running two functions on javascript node.js one after the other

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run two functions on javascript node.js one after the other
These are the two functions

This functions runs a bat file

```
function loadTime() {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
}
```

I have to wait for the result of this bat file to run the next function, which is

```
function parseTime() {
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    fs.readFile('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\2.sat\\2.sat.response.xml', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            var timeString = result.Message.Response[0].Events[0].MessageReportEvent[8].$.Message;
            var fileTime = timeString.substr(13, 20);
            console.log(fileTime);
        });
    });
}
```

But in javascript when I run this as

```
loadTime();
parseTime();
```

It seems `parseTime()` function starts to run before `loadTime()` finishes running. How do I run `parseTime()` after `loadTime()` is finished?

Comment: Make `loadTime` accept a callback and call that callback when the function is done.

Comment: See [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2190850/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply give `loadTime()` a callback function that executes once it's finished loading, and have this callback function be your `parseTime()`

Something like this might work (I haven't tested it)

```
function loadTime(callback){
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }else{
            // Assuming you want parseTime() to fire if there were no errors in loadTime()
            // When we reach this point, we want to fire our callback function
            callback();
        }
    }
);

function parseTime(){
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    fs.readFile('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\2.sat\\2.sat.response.xml', function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            var timeString = result.Message.Response[0].Events[0].MessageReportEvent[8].$.Message;
            var fileTime = timeString.substr(13,20);
            console.log(fileTime);
         });
     });
};

// We call loadTime() with parseTime() as its callback
loadTime(function(){
    parseTime();
});
```

Comment: Also you can do loadTime(parseTime);

Comment: @Ziki Yeah I believe that works too; I guess it's just preference

Answer (score 1):

either you can call parseTime() method inside loadTime() so that once loadTime() completes then only parseTime() is called. Else you can use **async** module of nodejs to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

function loadTime(done) {

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\runme.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);

    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }

    done();
});


function parseTime() {

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    fs.readFile('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\2.sat\\2.sat.response.xml', function(err, data) {

        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {

            var timeString = result.Message.Response[0].Events[0].MessageReportEvent[8].$.Message;
            var fileTime = timeString.substr(13, 20);

            console.log(fileTime);


        });

    });

};


loadTime(
    function() {
        parseTime();
    }
);
```

Comment: Just posting code without any explanation is not really helpful for a beginner.

Comment: Also you can do `loadTime(parseTime);`

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your functions to accept callbacks like this:

```
function first(callback) {
    console.log("First!");
    callback();
}
function second() {
    console.log("Second!");
}
first(second);
```

Should output to console: First! Second!

You'll more than likely want to be able to make callback optional so it won't error if it's not passed:

`if ( callback ) callback();`