# How to Know when a function Completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to find out when a function completes. I need to run another function but only after one function completes. Something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Except with a function rather than the document.

Comment: Look into callbacks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript

Comment: In jQuery you can use $.when for multiple functions or .promise for single ones

Comment: Does your code work in asynchronous way?

Comment: Gave you examples in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either create a [promise](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), or use a [callback](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

Here is a example of a **promise** (it has a success (resolve), and reject(something went wrong)):

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything is OK */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else { // something went wrong
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

And you use it like this:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

And here is a example of **callback**:

```
function giveMeAlert(callback) {
    alert('I am main function');
    callback();
}

giveMeAlert(function() {
    alert('I am a callback function.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery deferred like this:

```
var myPromise = function() {
    var dfd = $.deferred();

    if (/* this i ok*/) {
        dfd.resolve( /* somthing to send with the result */ );
    } else {
        dfd.reject( /* somthing to send with the result */);
    }

    return dfd.promise();
}

myPromise().then(function succsses( /* the message*/ ) {

    },
    function fail(/* the message*/ ) {

    });
```