# Javascript: Create call back for function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is very simple.

```
 subscribePresence();
 getValidationData();
```

getValidationData() must be called only when subscribePresence(); finishes its execution. is there any way of doing it ?

Comment: What does the first function execute?

Comment: It seems like you know what a *callback* is, so what have you tried?

Comment: That's exactly how Javascript works. The code you have supplied will guarantee that `subscribePresence();` finishes executing before `getValidationData();` is called. JavaScript executes code in order. Whether or not `subscribePresence();` starts some other asynchronous task has nothing to do with it finishing its execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript)

Comment: Show us the code for `subscribePresence()` so we can see whether it is asynchronous or not and, if so, how to know when it is done with its work.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `getValidationData();` as callback function into first `function`.

**Ex:**

```
function subscribePresence(callback){
  //do your stuffs
  callback();
}
```

Now call your `subscribePresence()` as below

```
subscribePresence(getValidationData);
```