# Angularjs asynchronous callback handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

```
$scope.$watch('Status.statusId', function (data) {

    GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers();

    if (($scope.gridDisplayObjectList.length <= 0) || ($scope.Status && $scope.Status.statusId == 325) || ($scope.Status && $scope.Status.statusId == 326)) {
        $scope.IsApproveVisible = false;
        $scope.IsRejectVisible = false;
        $scope.IsSaveVisible = false;
    } else {
        $scope.IsSaveVisible = true;
    }

    if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
}, true);
```

In above code the *$scope.$watch() function* calls *GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers() function* .What I expected from *$scope.$watch() function* is after executing *GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers()* completely it will execute other statements in *$scope.$watch() function* .But I am wrong this case.

```
function GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers() {
    customerWiseRmTransferService.GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers({
        statusId: angular.toJson($scope.Status.statusId)
    }, function (data) {
        $scope.gridDisplayObjectList = data;

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.gridDisplayObjectList.length; i++) {
            var fdate = ToJavaScriptDate($scope.gridDisplayObjectList[i].RequestedDate);
            $scope.gridDisplayObjectList[i].RequestedDate = fdate;
        }

        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
                inputs[i].checked = false;
            }
        }

        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

Within *GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers() function* it has an AJAX call to another function.So After excecuting AJAX function it exits from the function and executes the statements in  *$scope.$watch() function*. After complete executing all statements in *$scope.$watch()* ,then *GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers()* executes remainging Callback Function.

But what I want is after completely executing *GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers() function*,*$scope.$watch()*  should execute remaining Statements.

Can somebody share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Very nearly duplicates [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (or maybe it's not just near).

Answer (score 2):

Modify `GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers` to accept a callback it calls when the ajax work is complete, or have it return a promise it resolves when the ajax work is complete, and use that callback/promise in the code in `$watch`.

Re

> How can i modify to accept callback ?

See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript), which I found using the search `[js] create callback`.

Basically, you

1. Add an argument to your `GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers`
2. Call it from within the ajax completion callback
3. Pass a function to `GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers` when you call it, just like you do with `$watch`, `setTimeout`, an event handler, ...

So:

```
function GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers(callback) {
// Declare it ----------------------^
    // ...
        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();

        callback(); // <==== Call it
    });
};
```

And when calling it, move everything after the call to `GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers` in your `$watch` callback *into* the function you pass in:

```
GetCustomerWiseRmTransfers(function() {
    // ...everything that followed it in the $watch callback...
});
```

Comment: How can i modify to accept callback ?.. I am using angularjs.

Comment: @AslamJiffry: Have you looked for how to do that? There's [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript), for instance. (I just did a search; the fact one of those answers is mine is a bit of a coincidence. :-) )

Comment: Yes I did, I tried to use Queing functions according to order that need to execute using angular.But it didn't work.

Comment: @AslamJiffry: I have no idea what a "queening function" is, I'm afraid. But the answers in that link show exactly how to create a callback and call it.

Comment: @AslamJiffry: I've updated the answer to fold some of the linked content in. I'm trying not to just write it for you, as you won't learn anything that way.