# functionName is not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am trying to use a callback function to place data into an array. When i try to call my callback function 'myCallback' i get an error saying `TypeError: callbackFunction is not a function`. Here is an example of what the code looks like.

```
var content = [];

var function1 = function(){
  var function2 = function(){
    query = function(){
      //CAML code
    }
    success = function(callbackFunction){
      callbackFunction("text");// TypeError: callbackFunction is not a function
    }
    failure = function(){
      //Error code
    }
  }
  function2();
  runQuery(one, query, success, failure, two);//Main function
}

function1();

function callbackfunction(data){
  content.push(data)
}
```

I am following [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190872/4975671) Stack Overflow answer. Maybe I am getting something confused? Not really sure why it is throwing me the error when it is clearly defined in the code.

Thanks pals.

Comment: Well you defined them inside of function2() and function2 never runs... That pattern makes no sense...

Comment: It runs, my example is just that. An EXAMPLE. it might not look the same but it runs..

Comment: Well your example does not and that is what we have to go off of...

Comment: So now your issue is you defined callbackFunction as a variable, you need to pass the callback function into the function to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefined the variable, you need to pass it in.

```
var content = [];

var function1 = function(callbackfunction){
  var function2 = function(){
    query = function(){
      //CAML code
    }
    success = function(){
      callbackFunction("text");// TypeError: callbackFunction is not a function
    }
    failure = function(){
      //Error code
    }
  }
  function2();
  runQuery(one, query, success, failure, two);//Main function
}

function1(callbackfunction);

function callbackfunction(data){  
  content.push(data)
}
```

And if that is your actual code, you will have issues with global variables if you make more than one call.

Answer (score 0):

The variable named `callbackFunction` passes to the `success` function has *any type* but a function and can't be called.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not very complete, but I could try to guess that problem is fllowing. You are trying to call a scoped method from inside the success callback, but you overshaddow its declaration by local variable.

```
success = function(callbackFunction){
  callbackFunction("text");// TypeError: callbackFunction is not a function
}
```

Try like this:

```
success = function(){
  callbackFunction("text");// TypeError: callbackFunction is not a function
}
```

And also move the declaration of the callback to be at the beginning of your code for better readability.